# How to serve static files from GCP Bucket and redirect from any not found path to index.html with status 200 instead 404

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bucket

I'm working with GCP serving a single page application static files.

for all effects, not found paths, should redirect to index.html and the main script route will display the correct page. our set is:

GCP Bucket -> Load Balancer -> DNS

On the GCP Bucket configuration we set the `index.html` file as a 'default file' and if the 'not found'. it works like a charm, all routes are redirected to index.html as planned.

However the returned status is 404 instead of 200. This mess up our metrics and performance metrics.

the question is: How serve files for a not found path withn status 200 instead of 404?

for instance `/students/1` should serve `index.html` and the main script should display correct page with status 200. But now is serving with status 404.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: This is a great question. Sometimes you want to create a SPA and have nice clean URLs instead of hashes :)